# List query only giving first row of data from table using AWS Amplify in android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify

new to AWS amplify. This might be a simple problem but I am stuck.

I have a table with multiple rows in DynamoDB. Using AWS Amplify I run a query in my android code to get that data but it only will give me the very first row.

Here is my onCreate method

```
mAWSAppSyncClient = AWSAppSyncClient.builder()
            .context(getApplicationContext())
            .awsConfiguration(new AWSConfiguration(getApplicationContext()))
            .cognitoUserPoolsAuthProvider(new CognitoUserPoolsAuthProvider() {
                @Override
                public String getLatestAuthToken() {
                    try {
                        return AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getTokens().getIdToken().getTokenString();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("APPSYNC_ERROR", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                        return e.getLocalizedMessage();
                    }
                }

            })
            .build();


    findUser();
    getItems();
```

The findUser() method

```
public void findUser() {

    username =  User.USERNAME;
    runQuery();
}
```

The runQuery() method

```
 public void runQuery() {

    ModelStringFilterInput modelStringFilterInput =  ModelStringFilterInput.builder().eq(username).build();
    ModelOrderFilterInput modelOrderFilterInput = ModelOrderFilterInput.builder().orderName(modelStringFilterInput).build();

    mAWSAppSyncClient.query(ListOrdersQuery.builder().filter(modelOrderFilterInput).build())
            .responseFetcher(AppSyncResponseFetchers.CACHE_AND_NETWORK)
            .enqueue(orderCallback);

}
```

And finally the GraphQLCall method

```
private GraphQLCall.Callback<ListOrdersQuery.Data> orderCallback = new GraphQLCall.Callback<ListOrdersQuery.Data>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(@Nonnull Response<ListOrdersQuery.Data> response)
    {
        for (int i =0; i < response.data().listOrders().items().size(); i++) {

            response.data().listOrders().items().forEach(orderName ->{Log.d("list", orderName.toString());});

    }


    @Override
    public void onFailure(@Nonnull ApolloException e) {
        Log.d("eeeeerror", e.toString());
    }
};
```

I have over 18 rows of data in that one table with multiple columns yet only the first row get retrieved.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should first run your query in aws Appsync console to check your parameters and see how many results are returned. It will tell you if the issue is in your code or in the query itself or its resolver